# Counting how many of a certain character there are in a string with one while and one for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I was given a question with a random string such as

```
example = ‘asdkfkebansmvajandnrnndklqjjsustjwnwn’
```

and was asked to find the number of a’s in this string with a while and with a for loop

So simply using the count() function like this is not allowed:

```
print('# of a:’, example.count(‘a’))
```

We were given one example: (and were told to find a different way)

```
counter = 0
for letter in example:
   if letter == ‘a’:
        counter = counter + 1
print(counter)
```

I’m very new to python and I really can’t find a way. I thought of converting this string into a list that contains every character as a different object like this:

```
example_list = list(example)
```

but then I still couldn't find a way.

We were given two starting points, so the end code has to be in a somewhat similar format and we're not really allowed to use more advanced functions (simple string or list functions and if-statements are allowed as far as I know).

For while-loop:

```
counter = 0
while counter < 4:
    print(example_list[counter])
    counter += 1
```

And for for-loop:

```
for counter in range(0, len(example_list)):
    print(counter, example[counter])
```

I either end up printing every single character with its position, or I end up printing the number without actually using the loop.

Comment: So you need to use a for and a while? You can do this with a single for...

Comment: can you just rewrite the functioning `for` into a `while` ?

Comment: `sum(1 for x in string[start:end] if x == "a")`

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh I'm allowed to do that but I couldn't figure out how to because I'm not sure how to define the 'letter' with while

Comment: @DaniMesejo as far as I know just using the count() function would be enough but we were given this as an exercise to better understand loops so I can't help it unfortunately

Comment: @Shireen yes it is but I find it really hard as we haven't really done anything similar in the three introductory lessons we did. I searched everywhere and tried different courses to see if I could learn more but I'm very much lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the advises tell you that you have to iterate through array using a counter.
Here is the example for while loop:

```
example = 'asdkfkebansmvajandnrnndklqjjsustjwnwn'
counter = 0
a_count = 0
while counter < len(example):
    if example[counter] == 'a':
        a_count += 1
    counter += 1
print(a_count)
```

And for for-loop it might look like this:

```
for counter in range(len(example)):
    if example[counter] == 'a':
        a_count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that converting to a list isn't necessary, since you can iterate over a string exactly the same way that you'd iterate over a string that's been converted into a list.

For your first starting point, I think the idea is to iterate by index:

```
index = 0
counter = 0
while index < len(example):
    if example[index] == 'a':
        counter += 1
    index += 1
```

And the for-loop version would be:

```
counter = 0
for index in range(len(example)):
    if example[index] == 'a':
        counter += 1
```

Note: iterating by index like this is actually considered bad practice in Python (because it's basically just adding unnecessary work), and the preferred method is to iterate by value, as in the example you were given and then told not to use.

Answer (score 0):

Two functions, `while_count` and `for_count`, to achieve what you need:

```
def while_count(s):
    counter, i = 0, 0
    while i < len(s):
        if s[i] == "a":
            counter += 1
        i += 1
    return counter


def for_count(s):
    counter = 0
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i] == "a":
            counter += 1
    return counter
```

You can make the `for` case much simpler using a list comprehension:

```
def for_count2(s):
    return sum([x=="a" for x in s])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for your question

**1.Using for loop**

```
example = 'asdkfkebansmvajandnrnndklqjjsustjwnwn'
count=0
for i in example:
    if i.lower()=='a':
        count+=1
print(count)
```

**2. Using While loop:**

```
example = 'asdkfkebansmvajandnrnndklqjjsustjwnwn'
loop_count=0
a_counter=0
lis=list(example)
while loop_count<len(example):
    if lis[loop_count]=='a':
        a_counter+=1
    loop_count+=1
print(a_counter)
```

**Might it help if it does vote my ans up**